# Image rotating the wrong way

Tags: python, image, pygame, rotation

In my game I am creating a turret (a type of machine gun you use on the ground). The problem is that I am using a joystick to move the character, when the joystick is downwards the y speed is positive (so it can move downwards) the opposite is for if you move upwards. Then if checks your current angle and sees which direction you are pointing in if one of the if statements happen then it will allow you to move. What the main issue is that when I move my joystick upwards the gun points dowanrds.

I have already tried making a variable that stores the direction but that lead to the same problem so I discarded that idea and went back to the one I had before. There is also a turret stand where the turret is drawn onto

```
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    joystick.init()

turret_stand_pic = pygame.image.load("C:/knuckles_pictures/turret_stand.png").convert_alpha()
class Turret_stand():
    def __init__(self, x, y, picture, picture_tag):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.picture = picture
        super().__init__()
        self.picture = pygame.transform.scale(self.picture, (200, 200))
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos
        self.tag = picture_tag

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


turret_gun_pic = pygame.image.load("C:/knuckles_pictures/turret_gun.png").convert_alpha()
class Turret_gun():
    def __init__(self, x, y, picture, picture_tag):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.picture = picture
        super().__init__()
        self.picture = pygame.transform.scale(self.picture, (200, 80))
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos
        self.tag = picture_tag
        self.previous_angle = 0
        self.angle = -90
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.facing = "left"


    def rotate(self, angle):
        if angle != self.angle:
            self.picture = pygame.transform.rotate(self.picture, angle)
            """self.angle += angle
            self.previous_angle = self.angle"""





    def draw(self):
        if self.angle == 0:
            screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos+70, self.ypos-70))

        elif self.angle == -90:
            screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

turret = Turret_gun(500, 370, turret_gun_pic, "turret")
turret_stand = Turret_stand(500, 400, turret_stand_pic, "turret stand")

while True:
    [...]

if joystick:
                move = 3
                axis_x_two, axis_y_two = (joystick.get_axis(3), joystick.get_axis(2))
                if abs(axis_x_two) > 0.1:
                    turret.speed_x = move * axis_x_two
                    turret.speed_y = move * axis_y_two

                turret.speed_y = round(int(turret.speed_y))
                turret.speed_x = round(int(turret.speed_x))


if turret.angle == -90 and turret.speed_y == -3 and turret.speed_x <= 1 and turret.speed_x >= -1:
            turret.rotate(90)

        if turret.angle == 0 and turret.speed_x == -3 and turret.speed_y <= 1 and turret.speed_y >= -1:
            turret.rotate(-90)

turret.update()
turret.draw()
```

The actual results are that when you push the joystick upwards the machine gun points downwards. Heres what I mean:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In this case the turret ends up pointing downards:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aheix.jpg

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

What I should expect is that when I move the joystick upwards the turret points upwards.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFyg5.jpg

[image]

Sometimes the gun does not show when the joystick is pointing right:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to reverse the direction that you rotate the image. So, to flip it, rotate it an additional 180 degrees.
Change the line in your `rotate` method to

`self.picture = pygame.transform.rotate(self.picture, angle+180)`

I don't know your exact setup, but this might work only for the up/down case. The gun might still point right if you put the stick left. If this happens, change it to

`self.picture = pygame.transform.rotate(self.picture, 180-angle)`

This doesn't just flip it, the direction of rotation is reversed. Increasing the angle actually decreases the rotation.

Again, that might not work. It could point right if you move the stick up. If so, try changing the 180 to another number, like 90 or 270. This offsets the rotation by 90 degrees in one direction or the other.

`self.picture = pygame.transform.rotate(self.picture, 90-angle)`

or

`self.picture = pygame.transform.rotate(self.picture, 270-angle)`

Comment: It works for making if face upwards, but now the gun disappears when pointing the joystick right. I have tried using all 3 methods but all still do the same effect

Comment: I have just checked and when the joystick is at right the angle is at 90 degrees but the gun does not show (shown above)

Comment: @Jezza_bot That might have something to do with your special `-90` case in your gun's `draw` method. Try removing that and just draw it the same way as your `0` case. Or, maybe you should add some `+` or `-` to that case like you did in your `0`, but with different numbers.